# Geotrellis.spark._ is not a member of package Geotrellis when pulled from current master?

Tags: scala, geotrellis

I downloaded Geotrellis and am attempting to follow instructions found at:  https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis
I pulled in the resolvers and the libraryDependency into my build.sbt file.

Installed: 
Spark 2.1.1 
Scala 2.11.12
Java 8 JRE and JDK installed.

Environment:
Mac 10.14.4 Mojave

I have tried the following to resolve this issue but have had no luck resolving the issue:

Downgraded Spark to version 2.1.1 (referenced version of spark) previously used 2.3.3 and 2.4.3
Updated Scala to version 2.11.12 
Ensured that Java version is version 8 in JRE and JDK
Verified that Scala is correctly configured
Verified that Java is correctly configured

Going into Geotrellis-master (as of 16 May 2019) --> Run command './sbt'  and get positive feedback that there is no issues  --> Run command 'console'  and get error.
error: object spark is not a member of package geotrellis
             import geotrellis.spark._

I previously had issues where it stated that:
scala> :12: error: not found: value geotrellis
             import geotrellis.raster._
                    ^
:13: error: not found: value geotrellis
             import geotrellis.vector._
                    ^
:14: error: not found: value geotrellis
             import geotrellis.proj4._
                    ^
:15: error: not found: value geotrellis
             import geotrellis.spark._

This was resolved by changing the Scala version from a newer version in 2.12.x to 2.11.x.  So I have been expecting a change to the spark version to resolve a spark issue but so far this has not solved the problem.  If anyone has any idea on how to solve this, I'd appreciate it.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to compile GeoTrellis or just to use the master branch console then it is a known issue / feature / bug. The current SBT root project doesn't contain all the sub-projects deps. If you want some specific subproject dependencies just select the project you're interested in and call the console, it will do the trick:

```
$ ./sbt 
$ project spark
$ console
```

Answer (score -1):

GeoTrellis Spark doesn't have Spark 2.1.1, you need to use spark 2.1.0 and only works with Scala version 2.11: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.geotrellis/geotrellis-spark

Then you should use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.locationtech.geotrellis" %% "geotrellis-spark_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

Also, you can upgrade to Spark 2.2.0 and use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.locationtech.geotrellis" %% "geotrellis-spark_2.12" % "2.2.0"
```